# Вырезка из слоя на CSS

Tags: css, html5, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример на картинке. По центру кнопка, справа и слева полупрозрачные слои. Вопрос как сделать правую часть фона на чистом CSS, хочется сделать это без вставки картинки. 
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно еще так. Но тут тоже есть проблемы:

1. Какое-то замороченное масштабирование. Пока не разобрался.
2. Полукруглый вырез сделан с помощью кривой Безье, это не окружность, а лишь приближение к окружности.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-image: url(http://beerhold.it/400/300);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
div {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M0 0 L0 100 L100 100 L100 0 Z M100,60 C 86.33,60 86.33,40 100,40 Z" style="fill-rule: nonzero; fill: rgba(255,255,255,.8);" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Приближение устраивает, там размер элемента не больше 50 px

Comment: А что мешает использовать `A` вместо `C`?

Comment: @Qwertiy уточните, что имеется в виду. Мне Ваша мысль непонятна

Comment: @Qwertiy только вчера начал вникать в svg, дойдем и до А. )

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, речь об атрибуте `d` тега `path`. `C` - это curve - кривая Безье. Точно задать ей окружность невозможно - можно лишь приближённо. И об этом сказано в ответе. Но ведь есть `a` - arc, при помощи чего можно задать дугу. Если нужна полная окружность (не рассматривал детально), то следует поставить две дуги подряд. Вроде кажется логичным. Вот я и спросил, были ли какие-то причины так не сделать.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, а мне всегда казалось, что дуги проще кривых Безье :)

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko в svg, в теге path есть буквы M L C и т.п. Они обозначают разные фигуры. Есть буква А, рисует дугу. По идее должно получиться ближе к окружности чем кривая Безье.

Comment: @Qwertiy fill-rule для А сработает? Дуги проще, но в доке кривые Безье были ближе к началу, просто не дошел еще до А. )

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, оно для чего угодно сработает - ему же всё равно.

Comment: @Qwertiy пытался совместить path и сircle - не работает. Вероятно в одном теге должны быть замкнутые области, чтобы работало...

Answer (score 6):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-image: url(http://beerhold.it/400/306);
  background-size: cover;
}
.block {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.key {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: .5em solid black;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="key">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AndreyFedotov, я виимо хреново объясняю. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на вторую фотку в посте. Может так понятнее будет. Спасибо

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko да, так более понятно. нужна ли адаптивность?

Comment: в идеале да, иначе б сделал картинкой и забил. Но с этим сам разберусь, подскажите с реализацией хотя бы этого. Спасибо)

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko нужно эмулировать бэкграудом кнопки общий бэкграунд. Подобрав позиции бэкграундов можно добиться иллюзии прозрачности кнопки. Но сделать это адаптивно почти нереально.

Comment: а без адаптивности?

Comment: без адаптивности все просто. смотри другой мой ответ. Во весь экран только сделайте, там 960px ширина

Answer (score 2):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  height: 720px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url(http://beerhold.it/960/722);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  backgorund-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}
.key {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border: 2em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  background-image: url(http://beerhold.it/960/722);
  background-size: 960px 720px;
  background-position: center center;
  border-radius: 10em;
}
.block1,
.block2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 480px;
  height: 720px;
}
.block1 {
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, .4);
}
.block2 {
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .4);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="key"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AndreyFedotov, как Вы считаете, вариант с использованием `clip-path: circle(50% at 0 50%);` может подойти?

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko Не может, потому что вот http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: я морально готов забить на семейство ie. Только нужен в итоге polygon, одна из границ которого будет вогнутой полуокружностью